# Winrm quick config shows error

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, admin, winrm

C:\Users\Administrator>winrm quickconfig
WinRM already is set up to receive requests on this machine.
WSManFault
    Message
        ProviderFault
            WSManFault
                Message = Unable to check the status of the firewall.

Error number:  -2147024894 0x80070002
The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, after a lot of reading and going through firewall restarts, service restarts, opening ports and that kind of stuff, the solution was quite easy:
**Just reboot the server**

This issue just went away

Answer (score 0):

The default firewall rule may be corrupted or not functioning as expected.
Running below might help, to set the fw rule:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" dir=in action=allow service=any enable=yes profile=any localport=5985 protocol=tcp
```